# Why NestJS microservice runs on TCP, meanwhile API gateway runs on TCP6

Tags: tcp, nestjs, nestjs-microservice

I'm trying to connect my Nestjs microservice to the API gateway but from what I see with command:
`netstat -tunlp`
The API gateway runs on:
`tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN      55235/node`

Meanwhile the microservice:
`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3100            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      55225/node`

When I try to log the client on the API gateway I get this:

```
1|api  | ClientTCP {
1|api  |   routingMap: Map(0) {},
1|api  |   logger: Logger { context: 'ClientTCP', options: {} },
1|api  |   isConnected: false,
1|api  |   port: 3100,
1|api  |   host: 'localhost',
1|api  |   socketClass: [class JsonSocket extends TcpSocket],
1|api  |   serializer: IdentitySerializer {},
1|api  |   deserializer: IncomingResponseDeserializer {},
1|api  |   onApplicationShutdown: [Function: close]
1|api  | }
```

Could the TCP/TCP6 be the issue? If yes, how could I bypass this?

I was hoping for it to connect to the microservice, but nothing happens.

Comment: Are these running on the same host? `localhost` may not be the correct `host` to use here, configuration depending

Comment: Hi, yes they are running on the same host, on my local machine. I tried with 0.0.0.0 and 127.0.0.1